# Unable to change the location of a file

Tags: javascript

I am unable to change the location of src attribute mentioned below

```
<img class="srcimage" src=server-side4.php/>
```

I want to change it to

```
src=scripts/server-side4.php
```

This is the javascript that is also included in the file

```
jQuery(".preview img").attr("src",base+'?'+jQuery("#realtime-form").serialize());
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

One problem could be that you're missing **"**

```
 ***<img class="srcimage" src=server-side4.php/>***
```

Change it to

```
***<img class="srcimage" src="http://example.com/your-path/server-side4.php" />***
```

Then if that doesn't fix it, try outputting your variables to see what you're working with. Make sure that all these values are giving you the results you're expecting.

```
console.log(base);
console.log(jQuery("#realtime-form").serialize());
console.log(jQuery(".preview img"));
```

If you don't want the src to be dynamic then remove that line of JavaScript.

Comment: it didnt help. i have embedded the above code in wordpress post instead of wordpress file. but i want to have the src dynamic.

Comment: This is in a post? it probably doesn't work because the path doesn't exist. Specify an absolute path and it'll work. Also, what do you mean "doesn't work?" Do you mean 404 (path will help) or nothing shows (your php code is bad)

Comment: yes it is in a post. but the path  <img class="srcimage" src=server-side4.php/> but <img class="srcimage" src=scripts/server-side4.php/>dosent works. and dosent work means nothing shows. how to specify an absolute path?

Comment: relative: "../somefile.php"   absolute: "http://example.com/somefile.php"

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
jQuery('img.srcimage').attr('src', 'scripts/server-side4.php');
```